# Не получается открывать php файлы через интерпретатор brackets

Tags: php, brackets, adobe-brackets

Всем привет, работаю в brackets, пробую открыть php файл через Live Preview. Сначала просит вставить базовый url для Live Preview(??), если пропустить - 'откройте html файл или убедитесь в наличии index.html для того чтобы запустить интерактивную разработку'. Создал index.html, бог с ним - ничего не меняется. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Решение: в окошко Live Preview нужно вставить локальный путь к файлу. К примеру, я использую xamp. Мой путь: http://localhost/demo/ . Всем удачи!

Answer (score 0):

[image: php]
На скриншоте используется расширение [Integrated Development](https://github.com/jadbox/brackets-integrated-development).
Устанавливаем его из Менеджера расширений.
Далее идем: Правка -> Edit Builder
Находим там: "cmd": "php $FILE",
Меняем эту строку на: "cmd": "C:/PHP-5.6/php.exe $FILE",
(не забудьте поставить свой путь до PHP вместо C:/PHP-5.6/php.exe).

Comment: Спасибо, но всё-таки, как использовать именно Live Preview?
И где взять путь к PHP? Разве его нужно как-то качать? Вы уверены?

Comment: @UnconnectedUnconected Вроде да.